# Elixir: Argument Error while accessing ETS from an Elixir Task

Tags: elixir, gen-server, ets

I'm currently trying to build a Redis clone in Elixir. As part of that effort, I'm using a task to handle a request to get/set and I'm using ETS to store the Keys and Values.

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib 3.13.2) :ets.insert(:kv, {"doomspork", "Sean", ["Elixir", "Ruby", "Java"]})
```

Here are the steps I took with the relevant code sections:

1. I created a public ETS table

```
 def init(_) do
    :ets.new(:kv, [:set, :public, :named_table])
  end
```

2. As per the [example in Elixir School](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/specifics/ets/#inserting-data) I attempt to insert and read from the ETS table

```
 :ets.insert(:kv, {"doomspork", "Sean", ["Elixir", "Ruby", "Java"]})
    IO.inspect(:ets.lookup(:kv, "doomspork"))
```

3. Unfortunately, this gives me the error described here:

```
[error] Task #PID<0.159.0> started from #PID<0.156.0> terminating
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib 3.13.2) :ets.insert(:kv, {"doomspork", "Sean", ["Elixir", "Ruby", "Java"]})
    (redis 1.0.0) lib/server.ex:61: Server.write_line/2
    (redis 1.0.0) lib/server.ex:41: Server.serve/1
    (elixir 1.11.0) lib/task/supervised.ex:90: Task.Supervised.invoke_mfa/2
    (stdlib 3.13.2) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: #Function<0.28410304/0 in Server.loop_acceptor/1>
    Args: []
```

I was hoping to understand why the error is occurring or how to get suggestions on how I might go about debugging this problem. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

I've listed the entire .ex file for reference. General feedback about the code as a whole is welcome too -- I'm relatively new to Elixir and would love to hear your suggestions so that I can improve.

```
defmodule Server do
  @moduledoc """
  Your implementation of a Redis server
  """
  use Application
  require Logger

  def start(_type, _args) do
    Supervisor.start_link(
      [{Task.Supervisor, name: Server.TaskSupervisor}, {Task, fn -> Server.listen() end}],
      strategy: :one_for_one
    )
  end

  def init(_) do
    :ets.new(:kv, [:set, :public, :named_table])
  end

  @doc """
  Listen for incoming connections
  """
  def listen() do
    {:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.listen(6379, [:binary, active: false, reuseaddr: true])
    Logger.info("Accepting connections on 6379")
    loop_acceptor(socket)
  end

  defp loop_acceptor(socket) do
    {:ok, client} = :gen_tcp.accept(socket)
    {:ok, pid} = Task.Supervisor.start_child(Server.TaskSupervisor, fn -> serve(client) end)
    :ok = :gen_tcp.controlling_process(client, pid)
    loop_acceptor(socket)
  end

  defp serve(client) do
    client
    |> read_line()
    |> write_line(client)

    serve(client)
  end

  defp read_line(socket) do
    {:ok, data} = :gen_tcp.recv(socket, 0)
    data
  end

  defp echo(socket, command_arr) do
    echo_statement = Enum.at(command_arr, -2)
    IO.inspect(echo_statement)
    :gen_tcp.send(socket, "+#{echo_statement}\r\n")
  end
  defp write_line(line, socket) do
    command_arr = String.split(line, "\\r\\n")
    command = Enum.at(command_arr, 2) |>String.downcase
    IO.inspect(command_arr)
    IO.inspect(command)
    :ets.insert(:kv, {"doomspork", "Sean", ["Elixir", "Ruby", "Java"]})
    IO.inspect(:ets.lookup(:kv, "doomspork"))
    case command do
      "ping" -> :gen_tcp.send(socket, "+PONG\r\n")
      "set"-> :ets.insert(:kv, {"samplekey", "sampleresp"})
      "get"-> :ets.lookup(:kv, "samplekey")
      "echo"-> echo(socket,command_arr)
      _ -> :gen_tcp.send(socket, "Nah")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access ETS before it was created. `init/1` callback is called within the process after it’s started, but the first access attempt happens from the task run by `start` which might happen earlier. In your case, this is an **[`Application`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html?) which does not have `init/1` callback at all**.

Simply move `:ets.new(:kv, [:set, :public, :named_table])` to `start/2` before anything else.